# Accessing an element inside a Vuejs component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to access an element from the dom from within my Vue component but I just get 'null'. If I go into dev tools and try I can access it. I'm assuming it's a scoping issue but I can't find the answer.

```
<template>
    <ul class="list-group" id="criteria" v-for="item in criteria">
        <li class="list-group-item">{{ item.name }}</li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        template: "report-criteria",
        data() {
            return {
                criteria: []
            }
        },
        ready() {
            console.log(document.getElementById('criteria'));
        },
        methods: {},
    };
</script>
```

Comment: The line `template: "report-criteria"` should be removed

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**VueJS 1.x**

You're probably easier off using the [`v-el`](https://vuejs.org/api/#v-el) directive, which allows you to map elements in your component to an vm property on `this.$els`.

Also, AFAIK, you shouldn't combine the `template` property with templates in the `.vue` file (assuming you are using `.vue` files, of course).

```
<template>
    <ul class="list-group" id="criteria" v-el:criteria v-for="item in criteria">
        <li class="list-group-item">{{ item.name }}</li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                criteria: []
            }
        },
        ready() {
            console.log(this.$els.criteria);
        },
        methods: {},
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 43):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36937719) posted by @nils is for VueJS 1.x. The `v-el` directive was removed in newer versions. It was replaced by `ref` attribute.

To achieve that same result in VueJS 2.x, you should do the following instead:

```
<template>
  <ul class="list-group" id="criteria" ref="criteria" v-for="item in criteria">
    <li class="list-group-item">{{ item.name }}</li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        criteria: []
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      console.log(this.$refs.criteria);
    },
    methods: {},
  };
</script>
```

You may find more info about that change in [VueJS docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#v-el-and-v-ref-replaced).

Comment: Note that the example is incorrect for Vue 2, the method is called `mounted` instead of `ready`: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

Comment: Hey, @Diego! Thanks for the heads up. I focused my answer on the directives and didn't pay attention to that. I've just updated the sample code.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps that worked for me:

1. Reference your $ref in the html element:

```html
 <p ref = "myref">Welcome to myApp</p>
```

2. Define a boolean variable in the script:

```
shown = false
```

3. In the update life cycle hook, keep this code:

```js
update(){

  if(this.shown){
       
     console.log(this.$refs.myref)
     your code
  
  }

}
```

4. Change the boolean to "true" inside your function like the below code:

```js
test(){

this.shown = false
....
some code
....

this.shown = true // this will trigger the code written in the update hook

}
```